# Rails middleware initialization block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a simple superfeedr powered rails app here.

Based on the [superfeedr-rack gem documentation](https://github.com/superfeedr/rack-superfeedr), I'm doing this to initialize the middleware (snippet from application.rb config block):

```
Configuration = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'config.yml'))

config.middleware.use Rack::Superfeedr, { :host => Configuration["general"]["hostname"], :login => Configuration["superfeedr"]["username"], :password => Configuration["superfeedr"]["password"]} do |superfeedr|
  Superfeedr = superfeedr
  superfeedr.on_notification do |notification|
    Article.create_from_raw_notification(notification)
  end
end
```

I'm looking for a better way to do it - I don't like to load my configuration file there instead of in an initializer and I think the block with the article creation callback smells. Any ideas?

Comment: Try Rails.configuration.middleware

Comment: @tapajos your answer was converted to a comment because it was too short. If you'd like to expand it with an example and a better description, you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on tapajos comment, I was able to to refactor the code using initializers. First I created one to load the configuration file:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../../config.yml', __FILE__))
```

Then I created another initializer, like this:

```
superfeedr_config =  {
      :host     => APP_CONFIG["general"]["hostname"],
      :login    => APP_CONFIG["superfeedr"]["username"],
      :password => APP_CONFIG["superfeedr"]["password"]
}

Rails.configuration.middleware.use Rack::Superfeedr, superfeedr_config do |superfeedr|
    Superfeedr = superfeedr
    superfeedr.on_notification {|notification| Article.create_from_raw_notification(notification)}
end
```

I also applied the logic described in this SO question to ensure the load order: [How do I change the load order of initializers in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779773/how-do-i-change-the-load-order-of-initializers-in-rails-3).